# Fast hash function for specific scenario

Tags: c++, hash

I'm looking for a fast hash function, for use in a hash table look-up. The input consists of expressions of the recursive form f(x, y), where x and y can either be functions with two arguments, or variables. A few examples:

- b(b(b(b,b),b),b)
- foo(bar,bar)
- a(a(a,a),a(a(a,a),a))

These expressions can be up to 200.000 characters long however, and I need to hash thousands of expressions into the same table. I found something that works somewhat:

```
int hash(string s, int n) {
    unsigned int v = 37;
    for(string::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++)
        v = (v * A) ^ (*it * B);
    return (v * n) % C;
}
```

Where the input consists of only the first 10 characters of the expression AND the length of the whole expression. A, B and C are 541, 733 and 941 respectively. This algorithm runs in under 100ms for several worst cases (long, repetitive, nested loops like the first example), but I get a lot of collisions  and I would like to know if I can get closer to an O(1) look-up even in these cases.

Comment: Why don't you compute the hash of an entire expression(using all its characters) when you read it? Reading requires seeing all characters, anyway.

Comment: Are the collisions due to equal expression prefixes or insufficient table capacity ? Is there a reason not to use the standard string hash ?

Comment: @ILoveCoding Reading may be done using `getline` or something like this, so it loops through all characters internally only.

Comment: Wait, you take the result modulo 941? Of course you will have a lot of collisions with thousands of expressions. There are only 941 possible different values of your hash function.

Comment: Yes, I upped it to ~20000 but it wasn't significantly faster for worst cases. I should also add that a lot of the expressions saves are sub-expressions, so I read over the whole thing once and save pointers to the subexpressions.

Comment: Please focus on the number of collisions, not the running time of an algorithm we know nothing about. That is, if you are sure that the performance problem is really due to the number of collisions.

Comment: I added timers for all functions, and it is the collisions that take up 99% of the time spent in worst cases.

Comment: @Arthelais Then computing a hash of the entire string should not be a performance problem.

Comment: @ILoveCoding That makes it go from running in 100ms to 20 seconds - the strings are incredibly long.

Comment: @Arthelais If they are sol long, how can you read them in under 100ms?

Comment: Hashing data/strings shouldn't take any significant time really. How big is your file? Here are some expected speeds, and a fast implementation https://code.google.com/p/xxhash

Comment: @JCash Sadly, what I'm using this for only allows for the C++ standard library. Thanks for the link though, interesting read.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can't you copy the function to your project?

About the requirements, can you pre compute the hashes? E.g. store it with the data on disc?

If you really need standard c++, I'd look into [std::hash](http://naipc.uchicago.edu/2014/ref/cppreference/en/cpp/utility/hash.html) and perhaps use it like so:

  
`const char* str = "foo";  
size_t len = strlen(str);  
std::string s(str, len);  
std::hash<std::string> hashfn;  
std::cout << hashfn(s);`

Comment: @JCash This is for a university project, and I'm not allowed to just steal 90% of my work. xxHash is out of the question because of this, but std::hash looks promising. However, after streamlining what I already had I did manage to get the whole hashing part to be near O(1), so unless the built-in is still significantly faster I don't think I'll be using it for now. It was also quite interesting to dive into hashing theory instead of just using a standard implementation.

Comment: Of course, I don't advocate stealing. I was advocating the avoidance of incorporation of a lib, the license would still apply.. As well, it would have been good to know that this was a school assignment, and you had to produce the answer yourself (Technically, your hash function isn't part of standard c++, that's why i suggested a different hash function)

For  std::hash, it's implemented differently in different compilers I believe. E.g. fnv in visual studio, and murmur2 in gcc, so I don't expect it to be faster than your hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uint32_t hash(const string &s, uint32_t n) {
  uint32_t step = 1 | (s.size() >> 4); // ~16 iters
  uint32_t h = 0x1F351F35; // Barker code - 2
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i += step + (h & step))
    h = ((h << 5) | (h >> (32 - 5))) + (s[i] ^ n ^ i);
  return h % C;
}
```